# Getting HRESULT E_FAIL error when trying to open database connection via connection file

Tags: arcgis-pro, c#, .net

I developed an Addin in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 where I am using connection files to open database connections at runtime. So far that worked perfect. The connection files are stored on a network drive, referenced in the Addin with absolute paths.

`DatabaseConnectionFile connectionFileValidering = new DatabaseConnectionFile(new Uri(AppSettings.Default.sde_validation));`

Now that I am doing some maintenance on the Addin I am running into the following error when trying to open the enterprise database:

`Database test_db = new Database(connectionFileValidation);`

I am getting the following error.

'Database test_db = new Database(connectionFileValidation)' threw an exception of type 'ArcGIS.Core.Data.GeodatabaseException'
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146233088
HelpLink: null
InnerException: {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}
Message: "A geodatabase exception has occurred."
Source: "ArcGIS.Core"
StackTrace: " at ArcGIS.Core.Data.Database..ctor(DatabaseConnectionFile databaseConnectionFile)"
TargetSite: {Void .ctor(ArcGIS.Core.Data.DatabaseConnectionFile)}

With respect to the error message I found some stuff that is not related to ArcGIS, but did not help either.

Can you point me the direction of a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I may have had the same problem in QGIS, where I had to use following:

```
db.setConnectOptions("service=yourservice")
```

Maybe it will help to find the solution.